# How to handle database instances with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo

I'm working on a little web-project-management-application.
I have a few classes like Clients(), Services(), Projects() etc.
Every class contains methods like getClient(), newClient(), editClient(), ... and every on of this methods needs database connection. I've included an extra PDO class.

Current code of my clients class:

```
<?php
// include database class
require_once('../../../lib/php/classes/database/database.class.php');

class Client {

    public function getClient() {
        $db = Database::get("default");
        $clients = $db->select("SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY name ASC");
        return $clients;
    }

    public function newClient($values) {
        $db = Database::get("default");
        if ($db->insert("INSERT INTO clients (name,initial,payment,hourly_rate,active) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)",$values)) {
        } else {
            print "Inserting failed";
        }
    }

}
?>
```

But I think this makes no sense. How could i do it better? First idea: constructor method, that connects to the DB.

Comment: Candidate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ perhaps?

Comment: This really belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com (unfortunately there's no option to vote to move to codereview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everybody seems to love a bit of dependency injection these days, this will decouple your database object from the Client class.

```
class Client {

    private $db = null;

    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
    public function getClient() {
        $clients = $this->db->select("SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY name ASC");
        return $clients;
    }

    public function newClient($values) {
        if ($this->db->insert("INSERT INTO clients (name,initial,payment,hourly_rate,active) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)",$values)) {
        } else {
            print "Inserting failed";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But where should i create the new DB Objekt (Database::get("default");)?

Comment: One little tweak you might want to make, type hint the $db variable in the constructor.  That way you can be sure that $db actually is a database object and not something else.